# Infinite set ordered like a "infinite tree"

Tags: terminology, definition, order-theory

Obviously I don't need to say that I'm still a newbie, so I'll try to explain my question with some pics too.

I have a infinite set  $T$ I have a visual idea of how this set is ordered, but **I don't know the name of this kind of order, and what are the statements that define it.** (for example total order is defined by antisymmetry, transitivity and totality)
this ordar can be visuelized like that:

if we have this for $A,B\in T$

[image]

only if $B<A$ and $\nexists C(B<C<A)$
with this we can see the set in this way

[image]

in other words from every element $A\in T$ there are $\kappa$ numbers ($\kappa \ge \aleph_0)$ of elements $G_i$ (the green points) such that $A<G_i$ and  $\nexists C(A<C<G_i)$ but exists only one $B$ such that $B<A$ if $\nexists C(B<C<A)$

[image]

I addiction the order is transitive, some elements can't be ordered (for example I cant $G_i$ and $G_j$ in the picture), it doesn't have a max and a min.

**What is the name of this order? Is a kind of partial order maybe?**

I noticed something, there are a infinite number of infinite subset that are totally ordered by $<$

I would like to know more about this order

**EXTRA** 
About how the cardinality of $T$ depends from the number of "branches" $\kappa$ ($\kappa$ infinite).

I'm a bit ashamed to show this but this is my naive approach to evaluating $|T|$

$\forall A (A\in T) \exists \beta_A(|\beta_A|=\kappa)$ that set $\beta_A $ is the set I showed in the picture as a green circle and all the sets are disjoint.
My naive approach is that $|T|=|\bigcup \beta_{A\in T}|$ that is like the sum $\kappa$ $|T|$ times. In other words my idea is $|T|=|T|\times \kappa$ so if $\kappa$ is countable infinity, the cardinality of $T$ can be every infinite cardinal. Is correct my approach?

Comment: Check out this [related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191588/problem-with-tree-definitions). It looks like your partial order relation is the inverse of one of type (i), there.

Comment: This reminds the notion of [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28descriptive_set_theory%29) as used in descriptive set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have drawn a rooted tree (definition (vii) at [the tree definition question Cameron Buie linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191588/problem-with-tree-definitions)), and hence the ["Hasse diagram"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of a [semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice), a special type of [partially-ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) (or "poset"). This semilattice is not [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributivity_(order_theory)), though. Also, if there are only countably many layers to your tree, then I believe you have a [graded poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset).

I think you should make another question tagged with set-theory if you would like to know the cardinality of some specific trees you construct in this way.